# Serve Image with IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, ihttphandler

I am working with a web server that is only available on our internal network. I have a need to make an image it serves available to the public via our DMZ web server. The internal system has a GUI where anyone can upload any type of image so my HttpHandler must be flexible.

The bit of code I am currently using is:

```
WebResponse webResponse = WebRequest.Create(imagePath).GetResponse();
using (Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentType = webResponse.ContentType;
    stream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
    context.Response.End();
}
```

This seems to work and it serves up images correctly on HTML pages, but when I right click in Chrome and select "Open image in new tab" I get garbled up text like this:

[image]

Any suggestions to make my code better or is this okay?

Thanks!

EDIT: Seems like this code snippet does exactly what it should do. The problem was with the internally hosted image itself. It Served the exact same garbled text even before running through this HttpHandler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content type header is probably not being set correctly.

Change it to `context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";`, but replace "png" with whatever the image time you are loading happens to be.

Comment: Add as much info to your response headers as you can.  `ContentType` is critical to get an image to display when there is no HTML to give the content any context.  And caching headers will prevent browsers from redownloading the same resource over and over.

Comment: The imagePath I am getting from the internal server doesn't have a file extension, it also is an HttpHandler that only serves images with the correct QueryString parameters. That's why I thought setting my context.Response.ContentType = webResponse.ContentType; would be the correct solution.

Comment: Is it possible that copying the entire output steam to my Response is adding it's own ContentType and I would then be adding it twice?

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, that's sound advice that the OP should follow as well.

Comment: @JaredFeldman, The most common image types (JPG, GIF, and PNG) all have magic bytes that identify what the image is within the first few bytes pulled.  If you can peek ahead on the stream you can determine what the content type is.  That's assuming of course that webResponse.ContentType is not correctly set (which it does not seem to be).  There is only one ContentType, so you can change it as many times as you want before you start copying the contents of the stream.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advise. It turns out that this was an isolated case with this specific image. Other images seem to be serving as expected on HTML pages and standalone. I dug deeper and served the problem image from the internal web server and get the same garbled text. So looks the code is doing what you'd expect.